# rolling dice 6 times, outcomes showing of 2 sixes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If 6 dices are rolled, in how many ways will exactly 2 sixes show up?

I was thinking that it would be 6*6*5*5*5*5, am I right?

Comment: multiplied by the number of permutations of that setup

Comment: Is outcome $161623$ considered to be a one that differs from outcome $623161$?

Comment: can you make more sense please?

Comment: Let's say the dice all have a number. Outcome $161623$ stands for: the die with number $1$ gives a $1$, the die with number $2$ gives a $6$,... etc. Outcome $623161$ stands for: die with number $1$ gives a $6$, die with number $2$ gives a $2$,...etc. Are these outcomes different from eachother, or are you only looking at the fact that twice a $6$ is thrown, twice a $1$ is thrown, once a $2$ is thrown and once a $3$ is thrown, so that the outcomes are the same. If you answer this comment then start with @drhab.

Answer (score 2):

First choose which (in order) will be sixes.  How many ways are there to choose them?  Then the other four dice can be any of five numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of dice counts, then first choose $2$ dice that must
take care of the sixes. That can be done on $\binom{6}{2}$ ways.
For each other $4$ dice there are $5$ faces acceptable (a six is
not allowed) giving $5^{4}$ possibilities. That leads to a total
of $\binom{6}{2}\times5^{4}$ possibilities.